# How to give local notification when user gets near some location (in my case it's a shop) when the app is in background?

Tags: android

I am working on an application which requires to give notification to user when he gets near my shop.

I have tried using service having locationListener which is giving notification when users locations's latitude and longitude are in specific range.

It is working fine but when the application is in background it does not give notification as it is a background service and if I use foreground service it is giving a ongoing notification which is not user friendly.

Is there any way to give notification when location changes even if the app is in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research , I came to known that this is because of behavioral changes in Android 8+, I managed to resolve the issue by using AlarmManager.